# Logic to record action in load runner

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

For the following scenario scripting is done and script is working but I need some functionality to be added to the script as follows:

Ø  Login part (in this script we have 2 login’s) both should be in vuser-init part

Ø  Functionality should be in action part

Ø  Logout (in this script we have 2 logout’s) both should be in vuser end part

Note: Script recorded using flex and web protocol and script is working.

Scenario Work flow:

1.User will login to the application using 9080 URL -(recorded the script in vuser init)
2.User will do certain functionalities- (recorded the script in action part)
3. User will logout from the  9080 URL (recorded the script in same action part)
4.User will login to the application using Pegasus 9081 URL -(recorded the script in same action part)
5. User will do certain functionalities- (recorded the script in same action part)
6. User will logout from the  9081 URL (recorded the script in vuser end)

Expected as follows:

**Vuser_init**
1.Login to -9080 URL
2.Login to -9081 URL (In the script recorded login in action part this need to be placed in vuser init for this I need logic)

**Action**
1. Functionalities of -9080
2. Functionalities of -9081

**Vuser_end**
1. logout from -9080 (In the script recorded login in action part this need to be placed in vuser end for this I need logic)
2. logout from -9081

Note : Here 9080 is dependent on 9081…

Answer (score 0):

See Virtual Table Server (or RabbitMQ or a Queue table in your database server) for sharing data between scripts.

It's improper process to comingle two business processes in the same script, independent of your choice of performance testing tool.

Record each of the 9080 and 9081 as indepedent scripts.  Modify 9080 to push data onto a queue and 9081 to read data from a queue (in Virtual Table Server or other)

Answer (score 0):

You can create 2 scripts one for 9081 server and 9080 for another server and at the time of execution in controller create scenario wise scripts. So there will be two scenarios running at the same time.